# Could not scan the data from keyboard

Tags: java

```
package com.inputoutput;

public class inputoutput {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner arun = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("arun");
    }

}
```

I could not scan from keyboard from above program. Can anybody help to find out the bug in above program

Comment: `String name = arun.nextLine();   System.out.println(name);`

Comment: There's no bug in the code. You're not trying to scan from the keyboard, you're just printing out the variable name of the scanner. You have to call one of the "next" methods on the scanner. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Why -1 vote.. Question is fine

Answer (score 1):

In order to scan you actually need to call methods of [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary) Class

In your case this will work

```
Scanner arun = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(arun.nextLine());
```